# Warum ist das deutsche TMA-System so lax?

Tags: grammar

Es gibt hier viele Fragen wie "Wann verwende ich Präteritum/Perfekt" oder "Wieso steht hier Konjunktiv, obwohl doch eine tatsächliche Aussage gemacht wird" etc. pp. Schlussendlich bleibt man dann gern bei „regionalen Unterschieden“, Kontext, Tendenzen, ist möglich. Es gibt, im Vergleich zu anderen Sprachen weniger „harte“ Regeln im Bereich Tense, Modus, Aspect (TMA). Auf der anderen Seite gibt es eine deutlich größere Auswahl (neun¹ mögliche Zeiten, fünf Aspekte² und sechs bis acht Modalverben mit Mehrfachbedeutung je nach Indikativ/Konjunktiv).

Beispiele sind etwa der verpflichtende Futur des Englischen verglichen mit dem häufig optionalen Futur des Deutschen, das verpflichtende Continuous vs. dem völlig optionalen Progressiv, oder die komplizierten Regeln für die Vergangenheitsformen, denen im Deutschen ein „mit Perfekt kommt man gut durchs Leben“ gegenübersteht.

Was aber ist der Grund für diese Andersartigkeit im Vergleich? Gibt es dafür wissenschaftliche Erklärungsansätze, so wie man z. B. die Normanneninvasion für die relativ drastische Veränderung des Englischen verantwortlich macht?

¹ +doppeltes Präsens-/Präteritum-/Futurperfekt (ok, letzteres ist *sehr* theoretisch). Tatsächlich werden die doppelten Perfekta auch außerhalb der Dialekte, in denen sie verortet werden, regelmäßig verwendet.
² beim/im/am-Verlaufsform, Absentiv, Habitual mit „pflegen“.

Comment: Ggf. Auch interessant für [linguistics.se]

Comment: Kannst du ein paar Beispiele bringen? In Deutsch und in einer Vergleichssprache, am besten Englisch? Dann wird klarer was du meinst.

Comment: Englisch kennen wir vielleicht alle, ist aber in Europa ziemlich untypisch - hat sehr viele Tempora und ist da relativ streng.  Ich nehme an gerade der Vergleich mit dem Ausreißer hat die Frage inspiriert.

Comment: Konkret zur Frage zu den Einflüssen auf Englisch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_creole_hypothesis und https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_English#Grammatical_changes (ctrl+F [aspect]): die Beliebtheit des Gerundiums sei vielleicht keltischen Ursprungs.  (Und Französisch dürfte wiederum auch etwas von den Kelten haben, und von den Germanen.  Kleiner Kontinent...)

Comment: Hier gibt es auch gute Antworten zu den Sonderentwicklungen im Englischen: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6859/why-does-english-have-progressive-aspect-but-german-does-not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Annahme stimmt nicht ganz.  Trotz seiner grammatikalischen Besonderheiten und Dialektvielfalt ist das Deutsche in Sachen Tempora unter den Sprachen Europas eigentlich typisch.

Französische und deutsche Tempora entsprechen einander weitgehend.  Italienisch - wie Spanisch und Portugiesisch - kennt das Gerundium besser, aber da gibt es auch keine Pflicht.

`Vado a scuola.`

Das kann genau so gut morgen sein, wie jetzt gerade, wie regelmäßig.  Ebenfalls wird die vollendete Gegenwart im Alltag (gegen den *passato remoto*) bevorzugt.  Dänisch und Niederländisch haben ähnliche Grundformen wie Deutsch.

Sogar Ungarisch und Serbokroatisch sind dem Deutschen etwas ähnlich in der Tat.  Mit dem slawischen Aspekt gibt es Nuancen aber die meisten slawischen Sprachen haben das Präteritum kaum mehr, und keinen richtigen Konjunktiv.  Auf Spanisch hört man das Präteritum öfter als auf Italienisch, aber die Regeln sind nicht so streng, und Dialektbedingt.

Also grob gesagt ist das Bemerkenswerte wie viel Grammatik Nachbarsprachen teilen obwohl sie aus verschiedenen Sprachfamilien seien, und dass bestimmte Entwicklungen - vor allem der Verlust des Präteritums außerhalb der Schriftsprache - parallel stattfinden.  Sogenannte Sprachbundmerkmale (*areal features*).

Weiter fern ist Englisch etwas strenger und genauer, und Chinesisch wirklich [frei bzw arm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinesische_Sprachen#Aspekt.2C_Tempus.2C_Aktionsart_und_Diathese).  Die Frage was global normal sei ist auch immer subjektiv; die europäischen Schriftsprachen sind besser geforscht, und es ist nicht klar ob zB Luxemburgisch genau so zählen sollte wie Bengalisch.

Comment: Idealerweise würde ich die Antwort noch tabellarisch formulieren.